# How to read json data on your own domain using jquery ajax and jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, and I want to read the JSON data on my domain, but i've tried all I could think about, but could not get it.

This is the code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "http://www.mmsbip.com.ng/accounts.json",
            "type": "get",
            "dataType": "json"
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var options = $("#users");
            $.each(data, function (val) {
                   alert(data.UserID);   
                }));
            });
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log("status:", status, "error:", error);
        })
    });
```

And the data on my server in the accounts.json is

```
[
{
    "UserID": "timotech",
    "UserName": "timotech@yahoo.com",
    "Password": "password"
},
{
    "UserID": "teslim",
    "UserName": "teslimbakare@live.com",
    "Password": "password"
},
{
    "UserID": "bola",
    "UserName": "bettyolabode@yahoo.com",
    "Password": "password"
}
```

]

How do I get this data from the server

Edit:
I decided to post the whole page so that you can see where i'm making any mistakes. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Simple JSON Example</title>
    <script src="jmobile/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                "url": "http://www.mmsbip.com.ng/accounts.json",
                "type": "get",
                "dataType": "json"
            })
        .done(function (data) {
            var options = $("#users");
            $.each(data, function (val) {
                alert(data.UserID);
            });
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log("status:", status, "error:", error);
        })
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Simple JSON Example</h2>
    <p>This DropDown is populated using $.ajax()</p>
     <select name="users" id="users" />
</body>
</html>
```

The alert is just to test whether the json data is being returned.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Also, are you sure that URL is right? (.com.ng?) I get a 404 when I hit the URL, but I'm assuming it's for a different reason.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? How do you expect us to help you if you don't explain what the problem is?

Comment: do you have an element with id `users` in your HTML? if not, the code will fail there (it should show up on the console, though)

Comment: If you want to use JSONP, then why are you telling jQuery to expect JSON and why does your file contain JSON?

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser. What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: @ochi — No it won't. Looping over a zero length array (which is close enough to what would be happening) doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Hi ShadowCat7, thats the same error 404 that i get, but i'm the administrator of the domain, so i know the file is there.

Comment: Hi Felix Kling, it does not display any error, nor does it bring any alert, so i myself do not know where i'm wrong

Comment: Hi Quentin, i do not understand what you are trying to show me, can you please give an example, and seriously i don't see anything on the console

Comment: @AyodeleTimothy — You're getting a 404 error? That's the problem. The server is reporting that the resource isn't there.

Comment: "i do not understand what you are trying to show me, can you please give an example," — Look at the Wikipedia page on JSONP if you want to learn the basics of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of small errors in the code. Try this instead:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "http://www.mmsbip.com.ng/accounts.json",
            "type": "get",
           "dataType": "json"
     })
    .done(function (data) {
        var options = $("#users");
        $.each(data, function (val) {
           alert(data.UserID);   
        });
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
       console.log("status:", status, "error:", error);
    })
});
```

You had closed the original function too soon (after the alert) and had an extra `});` in the code.